# how to remove "Archive | " from wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

how do you remove "Archive | " from wordpress category page and only show the category? is there a plugin or what code do i need to remove?

Thank you in advance ;-)

Comment: What have you tried? It is expected that questions here relate to a specific programming problem. Please post what you have tried and indicate where you are stuck. Simply presenting a problem and asking for others to write code for you is frowned upon.

Comment: @Imran, you may have better luck with questions like this at the WP-specific StackExchange site: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2):

What I imagine that you mean is that there is a header tag containing "Archive | " somewhere in your category page. If you want to get rid of this string, the first thing you should look for is whether or not this can be changed somewhere in a Theme Options Page (if applicable).

If you don't have a Theme Options Page, look for "category.php" in your theme folder. Inside there, you should be able to find "Archive | " fairly easily and remove it.

DO NOT DELETE ANY FILES!! If you're having trouble, post the contents of your theme's category.php file, and I'll be sure to try and help you further.

Comment: This is the right approach.  OP's question is theme dependant, and likely can be solved within whichever template file is used on these "archive" pages.  Its likely to be "category.php" or "archive.php", but use [this diagram](http://codex.wordpress.org/File:Template_Hierarchy.png?utm_source=wordpress-modguide) to help figure out which file contains that text

Answer (score 1):

To remove archive pages I use to do this way: remove the archive.php page from theme (most of time it's redundant and not needed, there already are tags and categories) and then add this small code snippet in index.php page of your theme. So users that try to fetch content adding years and months to your urls are redirected to standard 404 page.

```
if(is_archive()) {
    // force 404
    $wp_query->set_404();
    status_header( 404 );
    nocache_headers();
    include("404.php");
    die;
}
```

A longer post about that here: http://www.barattalo.it/2015/09/08/wordpress-remove-archive-pages/

Answer (score 0):

Try the **[WP No Category Base](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-no-category-base/)** plugin.

It does remove the `/category/` slug from your URL's, and hopefully it can also solve your question.

Answer (score 0):

I found an option to delete the Archive section in:

Customizing ▸ Widgets ▸ Sidebar widget area:

http://YourSite.com/wp-admin/customize.php?

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1rs9R.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Try the filter `get_the_archive_title_prefix` that filters the archive title prefix. It's used by [get_the_archive_title()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_archive_title/#hooks).

If you want to remove all the prefixes :

```
add_filter( 'get_the_archive_title_prefix', '__return_false' );
```

Answer (score -2):

Try to delete archive.php in your theme's folder.

Comment: Never ever delete core files.

Comment: I agree that they are not core files, but why on earth would you even begin to think that deleting theme files is in any way a good idea? It's not a hierarchy problem. At the most, one of the HTML tags needs to be edited.

Comment: remove archive.php page is not enaugh.