# How to remove certain posts from Wordpress.org archive

Tags: wordpress, archive, categories

I'm using Albar's premium theme for a website redesign project. My team is using posts in a few different categories for different purposes, but our client wants the archive to only show news stories. I know I could make a custom sidebar but I feel like that may be difficult for the client to update. Albar theme settings have blog settings that let you exclude certain categories from the blog, but they're still showing up in the archive. Is there any easy way to manually prevent certain categories or posts from be displayed?

Comment: what are you tried for this please put here.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11583954/how-to-remove-archive-from-wordpress

Comment: You'll probably need to write a custom query for your `archives.php` theme file. https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query